# How can you use INotifyDataErrorInfo/ValidationSummary for server side validation?

Tags: c#, silverlight, validation, client

I have various client side validation rules I'm using such as `Required` on certain fields. I also have some database validation rules such as unique constraints that really need to be done server-side. I've bubbled the error messages back up to the client, but how can I show them using INotifyDataErrorInfo/ValidationSummary?

If at all possible I'd like these errors to be shown in the ValidationSummary control as well as the control/property that caused the error. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

here is a post explain Asynchronous validation : http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2009/11/22/silverlight-4-and-asynchronous-validation-with-inotifydataerrorinfo.aspx

in your case, you will have to set your additionnal asynchronous ValidationAttribute onto the Class itself ! (witch will add validations errors to your object)